# Spring Framework : javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Tags: spring

i have created very simple spring program which display a jsp file using Controller file
It Showing following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cacheManager' available
```

Comment: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cacheManager'`

Comment: you need to explain more on what you're trying to do.. your config, pom.xml, controller, etc, etc.